# Problem when trying to run shell script : No such file or directory for testing purposes

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I am using the following code to run my tests

```
PROJDIR=$(pwd)
echo PROJDIR = $PROJDIR
/data/precima_rnd/dev/core/pme/ModelEngine/PrecimaModelEngine.sh\   
-s ${PROJDIR}/model_specs.csv\
-x ${PROJDIR}/pme_params.xml\
-v ${PROJDIR}/v.csv\
-d ${PROJDIR}/data.csv\
-w ${PROJDIR}\
-mm`
```

It worked with me before but for some reason, it is not working at all.

```
-bash: /data/precima_rnd/dev/core/pme/ModelEngine/PrecimaModelEngine.sh-s: No such file or directory
```

Comment: According to the error message you don't have a script called `...ModelEngine/PrecimaModelEngine.sh-s` .. a space is missing before `-s`.

Comment: I am voting to close this since it was just a typo: you need a space after `.sh` and before the `\ `: `/data/precima_rnd/dev/core/pme/ModelEngine/PrecimaModelEngine.sh \ `.